# Searching text in a .txt file using visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a project that searches a document based on some words provided by the user in a text box to search in the text file.
I am using visual studio 2013 on a basic windows form application, and want to open file component based on the word in the textbox.
the text must open from the required point.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I have a form with a textbox that picks up text from the user and searches for those text in a txt file in my computer.

Comment: If you provide the code that you have written to solve the problem we could help you on any kind of error you have but without any effort from your side it it just a _gimme teh codez_ kind of question. Not very welcomed here.

Comment: I have just started to learn the language and not so good with it. it will use of great if you can help me out.@Steve

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your question, you want to find a keyword inside a txt file based on the user input in order to do something, well. This is a little snippet to give you some example and a good starting point.

**Snippet**

```
Dim reader As StreamReader
Dim txtInput as String = "YOUR_TXT_FILE_PATH"

'The reader opens the txt input specified with the file path
reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(txtInput)

'Create a string from the txt file
Dim txtString as String = reader.ReadLine.TrimStart
Dim wordFound as String 

'Use Regex inside a Try/Catch statement in order to catch any possible exception.
'If Regex.Match doesn't find your TextBox1.Text inside the string it will throw an exception
Try
    'Use Regex to find your word or your expression inside the string created before
    For Each data As Match In Regex.Matches(txtString, TextBox1.Text)
        wordFound = txtString.Substring(data.index, TextBox1.Text.Lenght())
        'Do your stuff with your word found in the txt...
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    Err.Clear()
Finally
    'Close the reader before the Try/Catch statement
    reader.Close()
End Try
```

I suggest you to first read the documentation about [Regex.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2) and if you have any doubt feel free to ask.

**Welcome to StackOverflow!**